# How to stop variable over writing when iterating through object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, breadth-first-search

So I'm trying to implement a simple BFS search for solving mazes. I have a test_graph at the top of the code which I am using. When I iterate through this piece of code:

```
        for (var neighbour in graph[vertex])
        {
            console.log("neighbour :", neighbour);
            console.log("path :", path)
            
            let new_path = path;
            new_path.push(neighbour);

            console.log("new path :", new_path);
        }
```

I get the output:

```
neighbour : A
bfs.js:38 path : ["start"]
bfs.js:43 new path : (2) ["start", "A"]
bfs.js:37 neighbour : B
bfs.js:38 path : (2) ["start", "A"]
bfs.js:43 new path : (3) ["start", "A", "B"])
```

However, I want the second iteration of new_path to be ["start", "B"] not ["start", "A", "B"]. I would like to append the neighbours (A and B) each to "start" to create arrays ["start", "A"] and ["start", "B"] and push that into the queue.

Here is the full code:

```
const test_graph = {
    start: {A: 1, B: 1},
    A: {C: 1, D: 1},
    B: {A: 1, D: 1},
    C: {D: 1, finish: 1},
    D: {finish: 1},
    finish: {}
};

// Breadth-first search
const BFS = (graph, start, fin) => {
    var queue = [];
    queue.push([start]);
    var visited = [];

    while (Array.isArray(queue) && queue.length)
    {
        // get first path on queue
        var path;
        path = queue.shift();
        //console.log(path); // ["start"]
        
        // get the last node in the path
        var vertex = path[path.length - 1];
        //console.log(vertex); // start
        
        // if end
        if (vertex == fin)
        {
            return path;
        }
        else if (!visited.includes(vertex))
        {
            // for all adjvant nodes, construct new path and push into queue
            for (var neighbour in graph[vertex])
            {
                console.log("neighbour :", neighbour);
                console.log("path :", path)
                
                let new_path = path;
                new_path.push(neighbour);
                queue.push(new_path);    
                console.log("new path :", new_path);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

(the return is there to solve this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let new_path = path;` creates an alias of `path`, pushes to it (same as pushing to `path` directly), then discards the alias at the end of the block after printing. This means you're working with the same `path` array the entire time.

Most likely, you want `queue.push(path.concat(neighbour))` which allocates a new array, concatenates the new `neighbour` vertex and pushes it to the queue, effectively extending the current path by one node but without modifying it in place as `push` does.

Beyond that, objects with all values as `1` seems like somewhat of an antipattern for an adjacency list. A `Set` or array seems more intuitive here, so I took the liberty of making that adjustment as well as a few others.

`visited` being an array means complexity for lookups is O(n). Using a `Set` gives you O(1) lookups and is the correct structure for membership tests like this. In fact, `visited` is an unused variable in the original version, so if the graph had a cycle we'd get an infinite loop.

`Array.isArray(queue)` is an unnecessary check--`queue` is purely local and we can't reassign it if we make it `const`.

Lastly, when `vertex` is not in graph, it's not a bad idea to handle that by null coalescing to an empty array to avoid a crash (you may expect input to always be well-formed but it's a pretty easy adjustment).

Here's the code:

```js
const shortestPathBFS = (graph, start, destination) => {
  const queue = [[start]];
  const visited = new Set();

  while (queue.length) {
    const path = queue.shift();
    const vertex = path[path.length-1];

    if (vertex === destination) {
      return path;
    } 
    else if (!visited.has(vertex)) {
      visited.add(vertex);

      for (const neighbour of (graph[vertex] || [])) {
        queue.push(path.concat(neighbour));
      }
    }
  }
}

const G = {
  start: [..."AB"],
  A: [..."CD"],
  B: [..."AD"],
  C: ["D", "finish"],
  D: ["finish"],
  finish: [],
};
console.log(shortestPathBFS(G, "start", "finish"));
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Really appreciate the in-depth insight and have taken it onboard!